# How firebase store variable in database when there is no internet and deliver these variable later

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to understand how can firebase store object data for later delivery when the target devices has no internet connection. Because i want to create my one method that store a list of string when there is no connection and send them right after the connection is available.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase has two databases these days: the Firebase Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore. Luckily for the scope of your question their behavior is quite similar, but you'll typically want to specify which database you're asking about in your question.

When you make a change to the data in your app, Firebase does two things:

1. It updates its local snapshot of the data, and firebase local events for the change.
2. It sends the change to the server, to commit it to the permanent storage there.

If your app is not connected to the server, it puts the change in a queue of so-called pending writes. If you have disk persistence enabled that queue is written to disk, but otherwise it just exists in memory.

When the app is running and has a network connection, Firebase sends any pending writes to the server.

Comment: I'm using firebase realtime database, and i'm already enable the persistance.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I tagged your question with that information, which you can do yourself too next time. My answer is relevant for Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore, so should be good to go for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Sqite for store data then if internet available then sent data to firebase. Need some basic logical program.

Answer (score 0):

Create Database in your application and make one class which save data in your database
.when the user went to save data in firebase,checking connection if no save data in firebase and the first time that user open app with connection try to save it in firebase and delete data from data base

look more information at this [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)